# Drawing pattern by accelerometer

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I have implemented pin entry method using accelerometer to unlock android smartphones in Java, now I want to update it by drawing pattern using acclerometer. can anyone help me because I dont have any idea about it.
thanks in advance

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/main_view"
         android:background="#ff00ff00">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="" 
    android:background="@drawable/red_button"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text=""
    android:background="@drawable/blue_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:text="" 
    android:background="@drawable/rep_button"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
    android:background="@drawable/yellow_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/black_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
    android:background="@drawable/pink_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/org_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible get `Point.F` values from the accelerometer that manipulates a ball and have another mechanism to draw a polyline based on the returned values of the ball's position (the ball can be small so the user can see where the drawing is occuring) draw a Polyline accordingly (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html). I could help you later today, the code I have for manipulating the ball is on my computer at home, I'm commenting currently from a mobile device.

Comment: yes, please help I need it necessary

Comment: Did my code help or do you need further assistance?

Comment: Thanks alot but I have added seven buttons and tried to draw the lines (pattern) but I couldnt, can you help me to draw any pattern between buttons please!

Comment: I have downloaded what I have been added

Comment: I don't understand, what are you exactly trying to do with the buttons? Why is an accelerometer needed if the user can user their finger to draw?

Comment: Im try to draw pattern by moving the ball on buttons  without using any finger, its look like the standard draw pattern to unlock phone screen by using the finger but this by the ball

Comment: Is this a game or a new lock screen because it seems tedious to have a user tilt the device to draw a pattern. I mean .... it is very possible to do it but is it really something people would want to do everytime they unlock their phone...a finger is _much_ quicker. I don't mean abandon the idea but unless the UX is very clean and seamless it would be hard to market such a mechanism when there are simpler things out there. I honestly think it's a really interesting and original but is it worth it to develop?

Comment: As to your question you can have the ball light up the buttons when intersected (you have to make a machanism to detect that) and have a user preset pattern stored persistently in the app. If the button light up pattern matches what is stored then the user is let in

Comment: Then again what if the user is in a car?...it will be very hard to tilt since the cars turbulence will shake the phone. How big will the ball be?...what will you do if a user mistilts and highlights a wrong button? All good questions to ask practically.

Comment: I must do that even if  its tedious because this what the teacher need, but can you help me with some code to draw the pattern ?

Comment: I would love too but I'm very busy, try doing what I said above  and when you absolutely can't find a solution comment back or ask another more specific question on this site. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some open source code I found that can get you started:

Here is the MainActivity:

```
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class TiltBall extends ActionBarActivity {

    BallView mBallView = null;
    Handler RedrawHandler = new Handler(); //so redraw occurs in main thread
    Timer mTmr = null;
    TimerTask mTsk = null;
    int mScrWidth, mScrHeight;
    android.graphics.PointF mBallPos, mBallSpd;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //hide title bar
    //set app to full screen and keep screen on
        getWindow().setFlags(0xFFFFFFFF, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tilt_ball);
    //create pointer to main screen
        final FrameLayout mainView = (android.widget.FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);

     //get screen dimensions
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        mScrWidth = display.getWidth();
        mScrHeight = display.getHeight();
        mBallPos = new android.graphics.PointF();
        mBallSpd = new android.graphics.PointF();




    //create variables for ball position and speed
        mBallPos.x = mScrWidth / 2;
        mBallPos.y = mScrHeight / 5;
        mBallSpd.x = 0;
        mBallSpd.y = 0;

        //create initial ball
        mBallView = new BallView(this, mBallPos.x, mBallPos.y, 75);

        mainView.addView(mBallView); //add ball to main screen
        mBallView.invalidate(); //call onDraw in BallView

    //listener for accelerometer, use anonymous class for simplicity
        ((SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)).registerListener(
                new SensorEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                        //set ball speed based on phone tilt (ignore Z axis)
                        mBallSpd.x = -event.values[0] * (30/10);
                        mBallSpd.y = event.values[1] * (30/10);
                        //timer event will redraw ball
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                    } //ignore
                },
                ((SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE))
                        .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        //listener for touch event
        mainView.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(android.view.View v, android.view.MotionEvent e) {
                //set ball position based on screen touch
                mBallPos.x = e.getX();
                mBallPos.y = e.getY();
                //timer event will redraw ball
                return true;
            }
        });
    } //OnCreate

    //listener for menu button on phone
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add("Exit"); //only one menu item
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //listener for menu item clicked
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        if (item.getTitle() == "Exit") //user clicked Exit
            finish(); //will call onPause
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //For state flow see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
    @Override
    public void onPause() //app moved to background, stop background threads
    {
        mTmr.cancel(); //kill\release timer (our only background thread)
        mTmr = null;
        mTsk = null;
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() //app moved to foreground (also occurs at app startup)
    {
        //create timer to move ball to new position
        mTmr = new Timer();
        mTsk = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                //if debugging with external device,
//  a log cat viewer will be needed on the device
                Log.d("TiltBall", "Timer Hit - " + mBallPos.x + ":" + mBallPos.y);


//move ball based on current speed
                mBallPos.x += mBallSpd.x;
                mBallPos.y += mBallSpd.y;

                //if ball goes off screen, reposition to opposite side of screen
                if (mBallPos.x > mScrWidth) mBallPos.x = 0;
                if (mBallPos.y > mScrHeight) mBallPos.y = 0;
                if (mBallPos.x < 0) mBallPos.x = mScrWidth;
                if (mBallPos.y < 0) mBallPos.y = mScrHeight;

                //update ball class instance
                mBallView.x = mBallPos.x;
                mBallView.y = mBallPos.y;
//redraw ball. Must run in background thread to prevent thread lock.
                RedrawHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mBallView.invalidate();
                    }
                });
            }
        }; // TimerTask

        mTmr.schedule(mTsk, 10, 10); //start timer
        super.onResume();
    } // onResume


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() //main thread stopped
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        //wait for threads to exit before clearing app
        System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
        //remove app from memory
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }

    //listener for config change.
    //This is called when user tilts phone enough to trigger landscape view
    // we want our app to stay in portrait view, so bypass event
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

And here is the BallView class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class BallView extends View {

    public float x;
    public float y;
    private final int r;
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


    //construct new ball object
    public BallView(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
        super(context);
        //color hex is [transparncy][red][green][blue]
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF1325E0);  //not transparent. color is blue
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;  //radius
    }

    //qcalled by invalidate()
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
    }

    public int getRadius(){
        return r;
    }
}
```

And you'd use a FrameLayout with this code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:id="@+id/main_view"
             android:background="#ff000000">
</FrameLayout>
```

This will generate a blue ball that will respond to device tilting with movement accordingly. You can add a poly line mechanism by sampling the balls position and draw connected lines at those connected points accordingly creating a polyline that looks like a continuous smooth line.

Comment: I have added different button but I couldnt draw the lines between them can you help me in this point (just draw any pattern) this is what I have been added: